# QDockWidget is not docked on a QDialog

Tags: qt, docking, qdialog

Is it correct to use a QDockWidget on a QDialog? When I tried to use it, dock widget did not get docked on the dialog window. I could not resize the dock widget when I executed the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDockWidgets` have to be 'owned' by a `QMainWindow`, but you can of course put a `QMainWindow` inside a `QDialog`.

Comment: How can I put a mainwindow into a dialog?

Comment: @fatma.ekici The same way you would add any widget to a dialog - add it to the dialog's internal layout.